# Create Certificate with domain account

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-broker

Is it possible to create an endpoint in SQL Server 2008 Service Broker with support for 
Certificate based authentication and using domain account for Authorization?

e.g.

```
CREATE ENDPOINT ServiceBrokerEndpoint

AUTHORIZATION [domain\username]

STATE=STARTED AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 4022, LISTENER_IP = ALL)

FOR SERVICE_BROKER (MESSAGE_FORWARDING = DISABLED, MESSAGE_FORWARD_SIZE = 10, AUTHENTICATION = CERTIFICATE [CertificateName], ENCRYPTION = SUPPORTED ALGORITHM RC4)
```

Comment: The AUTHORIZATION clause on the endpoint only specifies who is the owner of the object. It has no implication in the actual Service Broker security (other than the side effect of automatically granting CONNECT permission to [domain\user] by virtue of being the owner of the object)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it possible to create a service broker setup where publisher end has both windows and certificate based authentication and subscriber has only windows based authentication. The reason why I want to setup service broker as mentioned above is because we have existing setup with certificates and want to integrate more clients with windows based authentication.

Comment: Yes, is possible. Service Broker authentication support mixed mode, simply specify *both* modes: `FOR SERVICE_BROKER (AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS CERTIFICATE [certname])`. When set up like this it will use Windows with other endpoints that support only Windows and Certificate with other endpoints that support only certificate. Btw, this applies as well to MIRRORING endpoints as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
-------------------------------------
-- connect to server
-------------------------------------
use master;
go
create master key encryption by password = '...';
create certificate [<servername>]
  with subject = '<servername>'
  , start_date = '20100216'
  , expiry_date = '20150216';

create endpoint broker 
state = started
as tcp (listenner_port = 4022)
for service_broker (authentication = certificate [<servername>]);

-- Export the public key to disk
backup certificate [<servername>]
to file = '\\someshare\<servername>.cer';

--------------------------------
-- connect to client
--------------------------------
use master;
go
create master key encryption by password = '...';
create certificate [<clientname>]
  with subject = '<clientname>'
  , start_date = '20100216'
  , expiry_date = '20150216';

create endpoint broker 
state = started
as tcp (listenner_port = 4022)
for service_broker (authentication = certificate [<clientname>]);

-- Export the public key to disk
backup certificate [<clientname>]
to file = '\\someshare\<clientname>.cer';

--create an identity for server and import the server's certificate:
create login [<servername>] with password = '...';
alter login [<servername>] disable;
create user [<servername>];

create certificate [<servername>]
  authorization [<servername>]
  from file = '\\someshare\<servername>.cer';

--authorize <servername> to connect on the broker endpoint 
grant connect on endpoint::broker to [<servername>];

---------------------------------------
-- connect to the server
---------------------------------------

--create an identity for client and import the client's certificate:
create login [<clientname>] with password = '...';
alter login [<clientname>] disable;
create user [<clientname>];

create certificate [<clientname>]
  authorization [<clientname>]
  from file = '\\someshare\<clientname>.cer';

--authorize <clientname> to connect on the broker endpoint 
grant connect on endpoint::broker to [<clientname>];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it possible to create a service broker setup where publisher end has both windows and certificate based authentication and subscriber has only windows based authentication. The reason why I want to setup service broker as mentioned above is because we have existing setup with certificates and want to integrate more clients with windows based authentication.